What experiments can be done or what observations should be made for a hidden variables theory to be deemed plausible or true?
In other words, hidden variables theories which are deterministic need evidence if they are to be taken seriously and if to be deemed true: what evidence would we need?
I know about the Bell Test which makes local deterministic interpretations of QM not plausible but: Statistical Independence is an assumption that can be ignored which leads to superdeterministic theories; we have non local deterministic hidden variables theories too.

I do not think you can rule out hidden variables in general, you can just render them more complicated. You can always write some very complicated hidden variables to explain anything.

@Mauricio By more complicated hidden variables, what do you mean?

Imagine some non-deterministic non-local superdeterministic hidden variables.  Such variables would be impossible to falsify.
